# How to skip inserting null value in Hive during merging/updating to those column whose field is missing from input.

Tags: hive, hdfs, bigdata, apache-nifi, kylo

I am streaming incremental web-log through Kafka and then storing into HDFS. My web log contains partial information ie. if i have 10 columns in my hive table schema i may receiving only 6 fields through logs whose value get modified.Now During updating/merging into hive table 6 fields get modified by new value and remaining 4 is replaced by Null.
Currently I am exploring Kylo/ Nifi framework for these task.What i'm looking for a way in Hive that those 4 column will remains same as it was in previous state.

Comment: Could you share more information about how your flow works? What's the previous state you're referring to? Could you share examples of what your data currently looks like and what you expect it to look like?

Comment: let's assume our web-logs looks like this 
{"id": 1, "fname": "A", "lname": "B"}
{"id": 2, "fname": "C", "lname": "D"}
{"id": 1, "lname": "E"}
{"id": 2, "fname": "F"}   
After storing above data into HDFS, HIVE select query look like this:
id,fname,lname   {1,A,B}    {2,C,D}  {1,NULL,E}   {2,F,NULL}     

In above cases when we insert data into ES we get resultant data as (Assuming id column represent unique id in ES index)
id,fname,lname    {1,NULL,E}   {2,F,NULL}   

We are expecting o/p something like this 
id,fname,lname   {1,A,E}   {2,F,D}

Comment: We don't want to store null in case key is not present in web-logs during merging.Can you guide us the right approach for merging? 
Note: We are using Kylo (Nifi processor) for executing all these task.

Comment: You would need to use a NiFi processor to remove the null values from the JSON documents before they're indexed. If you don't get an answer here you might try the Apache NiFi mailing list.